# How to get value from Map ? - Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map, list

I am trying to write a Trigger. I have 2 objects.

1. Timecard `pse__Timecard_Header__c`
2. Period `c2g__codaPeriod__c`

In Timecard object, I have a field called Project `pse__Project__r`.  Inside this field I have a field Region Id `pse__Region__r`.

Now, in Period Object I have a field company id `c2g__OwnerCompany__c`.

I am trying to compare the region id (Timecard object) with company id (period object). I have the following code written. I just want the final step to be done i.e. to get the value from map so that I can compare it.

```
trigger Timecard on pse__Timecard_Header__c (after insert) {

  List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> tc_list = [select Id, pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id 
                                             from pse__Timecard_Header__c
                                             where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()];
 Map<id, id> timecardAndCompanyMap = new Map<id, id> ();

    for (pse__Timecard_Header__c tc : tc_list)
    {
        timecardAndCompanyMap.put(tc.Id, tc.pse__Project__r.pse__Region__r.ffpsai__OwnerCompany__r.Id);
   }


    List <c2g__codaPeriod__c> periodDetails = [Select Id, c2g__StartDate__c,c2g__EndDate__c, c2g__OwnerCompany__c, c2g__Closed__c 
                                                from c2g__codaPeriod__c
                                                where c2g__StartDate__c IN: tc_set
                                                and c2g__OwnerCompany__c =: timecardAndCompanyMap.get(id)];
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Map has a [values()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_values) method but this returns a collection so you will need to use an IN term in the query:

```
List <c2g__codaPeriod__c> periodDetails = [
        Select Id, c2g__StartDate__c,c2g__EndDate__c, c2g__OwnerCompany__c, c2g__Closed__c 
        from c2g__codaPeriod__c
        where c2g__OwnerCompany__c IN :timecardAndCompanyMap.values()
        ];
```

Its not clear from your question how to further limit the set of c2g__OwnerCompany__c objects to one object for a pse__Timecard_Header__c object.

Comment: thank u...that is helpful. Lastly, I am creating a Map for Period object but here the Id is coming from Timecard Object and I don't know how to retreive that. 

`Map <Id, c2g__codaPeriod__c> pMap = new Map<Id, c2g__codaPeriod__c>();
    
     for (c2g__codaPeriod__c pDetails: periodDetails)
     {
         pMap.put(pDetails.Id, pDetails);
     }`

Comment: @sus If you can say exactly what field (on what object) holds the ID of the c2g__codaPeriod__c object I can add some code to get the right object to the answer.

Comment: I am going with an alternate approach so I won't need what I was asking in my previous comment. thanks though